# Remove diacritics using Go

Tags: unicode, utf-8, go

How can I remove all diacritics from the given UTF8 encoded string using Go? e.g. transform the string `"žůžo"` => `"zuzo"`. Is there a standard way?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the libraries described in [Text normalization in Go](http://blog.golang.org/normalization).

Here's an application of those libraries:

```
// Example derived from: http://blog.golang.org/normalization

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"

    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
    "golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm"
)

func isMn(r rune) bool {
    return unicode.Is(unicode.Mn, r) // Mn: nonspacing marks
}

func main() {
    t := transform.Chain(norm.NFD, transform.RemoveFunc(isMn), norm.NFC)
    result, _, _ := transform.String(t, "žůžo")
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: That's great--was aware go.text had some fancier tools for taming Unicode but hadn't seen a practical use like this. And it looks like I've missed some practical stuff from the blog. :P

Comment: This will only work for characters which have an unicode decomposition. For example character Ł (L with stroke) will not be altered (so "AŁA" will be transformed to "AŁA"), even though intuitively it should be translated to "L" (so "AŁA" => "ALA").

Comment: I get an error "transform: short internal buffer" for a long text file 47K characters

Comment: Great answer, but as `transform.RemoveFunc` is deprecated, it is prefer to use `runes.Remove(runes.In(unicode.Mn))` instead.

Answer (score 21):

`transform.RemoveFunc` **is deprecated**.

Instead you can use the `Remove` function from `runes` package:

```
t := transform.Chain(norm.NFD, runes.Remove(runes.In(unicode.Mn)), norm.NFC)
result, _, _ := transform.String(t, "žůžo")
fmt.Println(result)
```

Comment: `golang.org/x/text/runes`, to be exact

Comment: Confimed this works perfectly fine while the accepted answer did not worked for me as of October 2023

Answer (score 11):

To expand a bit on the existing answer:

The internet standard for comparing strings of different character sets is called "PRECIS" (Preparation, Enforcement, and Comparison of Internationalized Strings in Application Protocols) and is documented in [RFC7564](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7564). There is also a Go implementation at [golang.org/x/text/secure/precis](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/secure/precis).

None of the standard profiles will do what you want, but it would be fairly straight forward to define a new profile that did. You would want to apply Unicode Normalization Form D ("D" for "Decomposition", which means the accents will be split off and be their own combining character), and then remove any combining character as part of the additional mapping rule, then recompose with the normalization rule. Something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"

    "golang.org/x/text/secure/precis"
    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
    "golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm"
)

func main() {
    loosecompare := precis.NewIdentifier(
        precis.AdditionalMapping(func() transform.Transformer {
            return transform.Chain(norm.NFD, transform.RemoveFunc(func(r rune) bool {
                return unicode.Is(unicode.Mn, r)
            }))
        }),
        precis.Norm(norm.NFC), // This is the default; be explicit though.
    )
    p, _ := loosecompare.String("žůžo")
    fmt.Println(p, loosecompare.Compare("žůžo", "zuzo"))
    // Prints "zuzo true"
}
```

This lets you expand your comparison with more options later (eg. width mapping, case mapping, etc.)

It's also worth noting that removing accents is almost never what you actually want to do when comparing strings like this, however, without knowing your use case I can't actually make that assertion about your project. To prevent the proliferation of precis profiles it's good to use one of the existing profiles where possible. Also note that no effort was made to optimize the example profile.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking how to remove (or replace / flatten) Polish diacritics in Go, you may define a mapping for runes:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/text/runes"
    "golang.org/x/text/secure/precis"
    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
    "golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm"
)

func main() {

    trans := transform.Chain(
        norm.NFD,
        precis.UsernameCaseMapped.NewTransformer(),
        runes.Map(func(r rune) rune {
            switch r {
            case 'ą':
                return 'a'
            case 'ć':
                return 'c'
            case 'ę':
                return 'e'
            case 'ł':
                return 'l'
            case 'ń':
                return 'n'
            case 'ó':
                return 'o'
            case 'ś':
                return 's'
            case 'ż':
                return 'z'
            case 'ź':
                return 'z'
            }
            return r
        }),
        norm.NFC,
    )
    result, _, _ := transform.String(trans, "ŻóŁć")
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

On Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/3ulPnOd3L91

Answer (score 3):

Here is an adaptation of the JS code from here: [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript) which answers the comment of @paperback-writer about 'Ł' character.

I couldn't find this code in Go anywhere and this stackoverflow is the first result for Google query "go remove diacritics".

Hope it helps!

```golang
/*
   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
*/

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = []struct {
    base    string
    letters string
}{
    {"A", "\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F"},
    {"AA", "\uA732"},
    {"AE", "\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2"},
    {"AO", "\uA734"},
    {"AU", "\uA736"},
    {"AV", "\uA738\uA73A"},
    {"AY", "\uA73C"},
    {"B", "\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181"},
    {"C", "\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E"},
    {"D", "\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779\u00D0"},
    {"DZ", "\u01F1\u01C4"},
    {"Dz", "\u01F2\u01C5"},
    {"E", "\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E"},
    {"F", "\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B"},
    {"G", "\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E"},
    {"H", "\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D"},
    {"I", "\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197"},
    {"J", "\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248"},
    {"K", "\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2"},
    {"L", "\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780"},
    {"LJ", "\u01C7"},
    {"Lj", "\u01C8"},
    {"M", "\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C"},
    {"N", "\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4"},
    {"NJ", "\u01CA"},
    {"Nj", "\u01CB"},
    {"O", "\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C"},
    {"OI", "\u01A2"},
    {"OO", "\uA74E"},
    {"OU", "\u0222"},
    {"OE", "\u008C\u0152"},
    {"oe", "\u009C\u0153"},
    {"P", "\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754"},
    {"Q", "\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A"},
    {"R", "\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782"},
    {"S", "\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784"},
    {"T", "\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786"},
    {"TZ", "\uA728"},
    {"U", "\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244"},
    {"V", "\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245"},
    {"VY", "\uA760"},
    {"W", "\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72"},
    {"X", "\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C"},
    {"Y", "\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE"},
    {"Z", "\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762"},
    {"a", "\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250"},
    {"aa", "\uA733"},
    {"ae", "\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3"},
    {"ao", "\uA735"},
    {"au", "\uA737"},
    {"av", "\uA739\uA73B"},
    {"ay", "\uA73D"},
    {"b", "\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253"},
    {"c", "\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184"},
    {"d", "\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A"},
    {"dz", "\u01F3\u01C6"},
    {"e", "\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD"},
    {"f", "\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C"},
    {"g", "\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F"},
    {"h", "\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265"},
    {"hv", "\u0195"},
    {"i", "\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131"},
    {"j", "\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249"},
    {"k", "\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3"},
    {"l", "\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747"},
    {"lj", "\u01C9"},
    {"m", "\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F"},
    {"n", "\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5"},
    {"nj", "\u01CC"},
    {"o", "\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275"},
    {"oi", "\u01A3"},
    {"ou", "\u0223"},
    {"oo", "\uA74F"},
    {"p", "\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755"},
    {"q", "\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759"},
    {"r", "\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783"},
    {"s", "\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B"},
    {"t", "\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787"},
    {"tz", "\uA729"},
    {"u", "\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289"},
    {"v", "\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C"},
    {"vy", "\uA761"},
    {"w", "\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73"},
    {"x", "\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D"},
    {"y", "\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF"},
    {"z", "\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763"},
}

var diacriticsMap = map[rune]string{}

func init() {
    for _, mapping := range defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap {
        letters := mapping.letters
        for _, letter := range letters {
            diacriticsMap[letter] = mapping.base
        }
    }
}

func removeDiacritics(str string) string {
    reg := regexp.MustCompile("[^\u0000-\u007E]")
    return reg.ReplaceAllStringFunc(str, func(a string) string {
        r, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(a)
        if replacement, ok := diacriticsMap[rune(r)]; ok {
            return replacement
        }
        return a
    })
}

func main() {
    paragraph := "Têstôöłæ" // -> Testoolae
    fmt.Println(paragraph, removeDiacritics(paragraph))
}
```

Comment: Nice one, you might want to edit the example output because "Têstôöł" -> "Testool", not "Testoolae".