# Search by start string with accent

Tags: go, rethinkdb

I'm trying to remove accents of occurrences looked somewhat the same way that the function downcase.

Currently searching for all results starting with a string like that :

```
r.Table("places").Filter(func(customer r.Term) interface{}{
             return customer.Field("Name").Downcase().Match("^" + strings.ToLower(value))
         })
```

but it does not work with words with an accent in the word.

Example : with search word "yes", it'll find :

```
"yes"   "yesy"   "yessss"
```

but not

```
"yés"
```

What is the best way to remove accents in query to pick them up, too?

Comment: The term you want to search for is "Transliteration"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove diacritics using Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722450/remove-diacritics-using-go)

Comment: The duplicate suggestion is correct, however this is usually handled by the database's own collation settings. If you can get rethink's index to do this for you regardless of the client side implementation, it's a better option.

Comment: @jussius How can use this function with rethinkdb ?